# Why are there 2 breaker circuits running into a single light switch?

Tags: electrical, lighting, garage

I have a large bank of fluorescent lights in a detached garage ceiling that pull of lot of electricity if someone leaves them on, so I was going to install a smart switch to be able to turn them off automatically, or on a timer. When I went to find the breaker that ran them (prior owner left most of box unlabeled) I found a 20-amp breaker that turned them off. Flipped that back on, then flipped next unlabeled breaker to see what it did, and the **lights also turned off**.

To summarize: All the lights will only turn on if the 2 separate 20-amp breakers are both in the on position. Turn one breaker off and all the lights go off.

I took the faceplate off, and I see a red switch with 2 wires on each side. I didn't pull it to explore further since it's 20 degrees out there and my original chore clearly wasn't going to work.

I am used to single pole switches with a single wire on each side, so I am at a loss as to what's going on here.

Comment: My best guess is that originally there were two separate circuits of lights and somebody wanted to control them all with one switch and did it dangerously wrong. Upload pictures showing the breaker panel and showing all the wires going to the switch. Don't disconnect any wires - turn off the breakers and carefully pull out the switch to get pictures.

Comment: Could be a 240 Volt circuit for 240 Volt lights controlled by a double pole switch but on two separate breakers.

Comment: @JACK That is theoretically possible, but quite unusual. Depends on whether "2 wires on each side" means "two wires under a screw on one side and two wires under a screw on the other side" or "two screws on each side, one wire to each screw".

Comment: Seems most likely to me that somebody wired two separate lighting circuits sharing the neutral as a multiwire branch circuit, but somewhere between the first fixture and the panel the neutral was lost, and now the circuits are running in a series connection. If this is true you need to all the neutral connections between panel and lights.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact Wouldn't two wires under a screw indicate breakers in parallel, and both would need to be off shut off lights, not either?

Comment: @NoSparksPlease That does sound opposite of what is happening here. Bottom line: We need pictures.

Comment: I would test voltage with a meter at panel. With switch on turn one breaker off, if operating in series the voltage across breakers would read 0, but voltage to ground on both would read 120v. Turn switch off voltage at off breaker to ground would zero.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact  Yes, that's why we need the pictures you requested. The fact that it was a red switch kinda flagged it to me. That's usually a h.d. 20 Amp double pole switch.

Comment: Another way to validate @JACK's theory is to find the ballast for your light array and see if it has two hots coming into it. Or just get a pic of the model number and look it up. 

An alternative to just swapping out the switch that would save more money long-term (albeit at an upfront parts/labor cost) would be to swap the fluorescents for LEDs.

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the boxes involved please?

Comment: @WPNoviceCoder yeah, don't worry about the lights, they won't add anything to the conversation.  Modern post-2005 fluorescents are *quite good* and I would stand pat if you have those.  If they are buzzy, flickery or have trouble starting in the cold , those are "that 70’s fluorescent" and make a plan to move on.  I have been staying with Real Fluorescent myself, the new stuff is quite good.

Comment: Sorry beefed up my comment. Anyway, I'll see if I can get a better picture of the switch box. Lights themselves (8 fixtures, 4 x 4 foot bulbs I think) are 14 feet up, so hard to get info. These fixtures seem to use lot of juice. My caretaker accidentally left them running for a couple days and the electricity use jumped by 29 kwhr / day for those days.

Comment: I used to measure them. "That 70's" 2-tube fixture was 95 watts, a modern post-2005 one is 62 watts.  So in your case that's 190 watts per fixture on the high end.  x8=1520 watts (36KW/day).  You must derate 125%, so  1900W, so a bit too much for a single 15A circuit.  The lower numbers are 992W (24KW/day) and 1240W derated (works in 1 circuit).